# Did Loki know that Antonia Dreykov was alive?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, loki, black-widow-2021

In the very first *Avengers* movie, Loki taunts Natasha by telling her that he knows all the horrors that she committed in the name of Hydra. That being said, he had the Tesseract and even without it he was able to use magic.

Is there a chance that he knew about Antonia Dreykov being alive as well as her father? If that's the case, do you think that he would have used that knowledge to mess with Natasha's head even further if given the chance, since he was technically under the same conditioning that she was?

Answer (score 19):

### Unlikely.

Even with the Tesseract, MCU Loki wasn't omniscient, or psychic. He indicated that his knowledge of Natasha was based on information given to him by Clint Barton (Hawkeye), whom he'd enthralled using the [Scepter](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Scepter).

> NATASHA: It's really not that complicated. I got red in my ledger, I'd like to wipe it out.
>
> LOKI: Can you? Can you wipe out that much red? **Dreykov's daughter, São Paulo, the hospital fire? Barton told me everything.** Your ledger is dripping. It's gushing red and you think saving a man no more virtuous than yourself will change anything? This is the basest sentimentality. This is a child at prayer. Pathetic! You lie and kill in the service of liars and killers. You pretend to be separate, to have your own code, something that makes up for the horrors. But they are part of you. And they will never go away.
>
> <sub>*Avengers* (2012)</sub>

Since Barton wasn't aware (as far as we know) that Antonia Dreykov was still alive, it's unlikely that Loki knew that either.

Comment: _"Even with the Tesseract"_: Why the Tesseract? Surely the Scepter, or the Mind Stone, would be the more likely object to help here?

Comment: I mentioned the Tesseract purely because it was cited in the question (along with Loki's magic) as a possible explanation for why Loki could potentially have known that Antonia was still alive. I agree that the Mind Stone/Scepter would be a better tool with which to acquire that knowledge, although it would have to be used on someone who possessed that knowledge, and there's no indication that it was.